# Opencv convert to grayscale not working properly

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, matplotlib, ipython

I've been trying to convert an image to grayscale using opencv in Python but it converts the image to some kind of thermal camera image. What am I doing wrong?
Here is the code for image below:

```
img =X_tr[9999]
plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()
img = cv2.cvtColor(img.astype(np.uint8), cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()
img.shape
```

This image is taken from CIFAR10 dataset.
Thanks.
[image: Code and result after using opencv]

Comment: I just saw that there is actually already a similar question (not using opencv though). I will still leave my answer here, as the point about the normalization does not become apparent from the other thread

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Gray scale images, i.e. images with only one colorchannel, are interpreted by `imshow` as to be plotted using a colormap. You therefore need to specify the colormap you want to use (and the normalization, if it matters).

```
plt.imshow(img, cmap="gray", vmin=0, vmax=255)
```

Comment: I am so stupid. Thanks.